# Syntax for GRANT statement in Teradata

Tags: teradata

Help me to find out the Syntax for GRANT statement in Teradata

I have tried this `GRANT select on database_Name to user_name`, but its not working

Comment: What about the [examples in the documentation](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1149_111A/ch02.004.028.html) and you providing some code and/or database schemas?

Comment: What you tried is correct syntax. So what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I have never worked with Teradata, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't have an error message that says "*its not working*"

Comment: Its showing syntax error..I'll try again

Answer (score 1):

```
GRANT SELECT ON database_Name.table_Name TO user_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below command with "WITH GRANT OPTION"
   GRANT select on database_Name to user_name
    WITH GRANT OPTION;